# Generating random data for tests

Tags: testing, antlr, automated-tests

I want to generate some random data for tests based on a given EBNF grammar. The different tools that exist on the internet are oriented SQL queries, but I want to have different kind of data.

It seems that Antlr could do that, but I don't know how, because I know that it could be used just as a recognizer or translator...

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Thanks, even if I am "obliged" to use Antlr, but your answer helped me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR 3 has a RandomPhrase class that you could look at. It's not optimal but the basic idea is to choose random paths when you get to a decision point, a list of alternatives in a rule.

Comment: Thanks The ANTLR Guy, it dosn't work perfectly but I am trying to modify the code a little bit. Another problem, there is no enough documentation

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. It turns out that just randomly picking up half doesn't work out too well. I would look at the ATN data structures in v4 as those are better documented and cleaner. It comes down to just a depth first search where you take only one path at each decision point, randomly.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I will try also the v4 even if I want to be on the same version as my team.